# How to Copy a range of data from google sheets using an Applescript

Tags: macos, safari, applescript, google

I was wondering if someone could help me with a script that would copy a range of data that is constantly updating on google sheets.  The site would be open and active in Safari. So I wasn’t sure if I needed to command activate. 
This was my attempt, but I know I’m not doing the Safari part right.

```
`tell application "Safari"
 select worksheet "Sheet1"
 select range "a1:h1" of worksheet "Sheet1"
tell application "System Events" to keystroke 
  "c" using command down
tell application "Safari"
end tell
```

Comment: Safari knows nothing of how to `select worksheet ...` and `select range ...` because they are not a part of Safari's AppleScript Dictionary.

Comment: I was using the commands that I knew worked for Excel, and I know google sheets also has worksheet.  It was an attempt

Comment: @JBis, The OP plainly stated "This was my attempt, but I know I’m not doing the Safari part right." and that is why I made the comment I did to the OP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although possible with JavaScript interaction, AppleScript is not the best tool to use.

I would suggest using the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/).  You can easily read data with their API.  Since the API supports Java, PHP, etc. and not AppleScript it is off-topic for this site. I would suggest asking on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @SUBLIMECAL18 No problem. If this was helpful please marked as accepted and/or upvote by click the checkmark and up arrow to left of my answer, respectively.